# How to improve this plot? Behaviour of the derivative

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, graphics, code-request, code-review

I wanted to plot the function
$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2} - 3\ln(\vert x\vert +2)$$

together with its derivative
$$f'(x) = x - \frac{3x}{\vert x \vert(\vert x\vert +2)}$$

which exhibites a cusp point at $x = 0$. Here is what I produced:

```
Clear[f, g, plot, reg];
f[x_] = x^2/2 - 3 Log[2 + Abs[x]];
g[x_] = x - (3 x)/(Abs[x] (2 + Abs[x]));
plot = Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Darker@Cyan, Darker@Green}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[
     SwatchLegend[{Darker[Cyan], 
       Darker[Green]}, {Style[x^2/2 - 3 Log[2 + Abs[x]], Darker[Cyan],
         Bold], 
       Style[
        Style[x - (3 x)/(Abs[x] (2 + Abs[x])), Darker[Green], Bold]]},
       LegendMarkerSize -> {15, 15}], {0.2, 0.8}], 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y}];
Show[plot, PlotRange -> {-4, 3}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.05}], 
 Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
 GridLines -> {{{{Thick, AbsoluteDashing[{3, 3}]}}}, None}]
```

The output image is this:

[image]

(Forget about the legend, which I can move or shrink, not a problem now).

I would like to know how to improve that code in order to basically get the followings:

- First of all the derivative (green): why is there that vertical line on the $Y$ axis? Also, why the limits seem to approach $\pm 3/2$ instead of $\pm \infty$?
- How to get bold, or thicker, axes? I tried with the bold command for the axes but it seems to not work. Does it collide with other code by chance?
- Is there a way to produce the functions so that they are dotted at their ends?
- Since we are here, I take the chance to ask for general improvements, from some experts like you!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = x^2/2 - 3 Log[2 + RealAbs[x]]; (* RealAbs can be 
   differentiated *)

Plot[Evaluate[
  Join[
   ConditionalExpression[#, Abs[x] < 4.5] & /@ {f[x], f'[x]},
   ConditionalExpression[#, Abs[x] > 4.5] & /@ {f[x], f'[x]}]],
 {x, -5, 5},
 Exclusions -> All (* not needed with my version *),
 GridLines -> {Automatic, None},
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thin, AbsoluteDashing[{3, 3}]],
 PlotStyle -> {Darker[Cyan, 0.1], Darker[Green, 0.2],
   {Darker[Cyan, 0.1], Dashed}, {Darker[Green, 0.2], Dashed}},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   SwatchLegend[
    (StringForm["`` = ``", #, ReleaseHold@#] & /@
      {HoldForm[f[x]], HoldForm[f'[x]]}),
    LegendMarkerSize -> 15],
   {.275, .85}],
 ImageSize -> 450]
```

[image]

Comment: o.O Wow. Stunning!

Answer (score 3):

First, the limit of the derivative at zero is +/- 3/2 not infinity.

For simplicity, I eliminated the legend.

You must define the x and y axis separately.

I do not understand what you mean by: "dotted at the end"

```
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Darker@Cyan, Darker@Green}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotRange -> {-4, 3}, 
 AxesStyle -> {{Thick, Arrowheads[{0.05}]}, {Thick, 
    Arrowheads[{0.05}]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: By dotted at the end I mean a way to show the curves "go on"

Comment: Oh, Solved! I calculated the limit in a wrong way. I really have to sleep. I had to use log properties in order to turn that limit into an Eulerian limit haha. Forget the first question!